# Avoid creation of Dense Matrix on a large dataset in Python

Tags: performance, dataset, sparse-matrix, similarity

perhaps You might think that this question has already been answered but I didn't find anything useful on the internet.

I am trying to find similar users of a movies dataset, using **jaccard distance**. Each user has a userId from 1 to 1000. For each user, we store the movies he has seen (movieId) and the rating he has left. movieIds are integers from 1 to 100.000 and ratings are values from 1 to 10. If a rating is 0 then we suppose that the user didn't watch that particular movie.

So, our dense matrix should look like this:

```
            movie1 | movie2 | movie3 | movie4 | .... | movie100000

user1:         5        0       3        2      ....     0
user2:         0        0       1        4      ....     0
user3:         0        0       0        0      ....     1
.....         ....     ....    ....     ....    ....    ....
user1000:      0        2       0        0      ....     0
```

Notice that because the dataset is too large, there will be a lot of zeros. Also, this matrix is 1000x100000 size. This means that a normal laptop will need to utilize a lot RAM and the algorithm will take a lot of time only to construct the dense matrix. That's why i am trying to avoid this approach. Performance matters a lot.

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean a *dense* matrix? If a sparse matrix is too slow/big here, I do not think there is silver bullet: you probably need to choose between space and execution time... If space is a problem, you can work on a small subset of users at a time.

Comment: yes, i am sorry, i mean the dense matrix.

Comment: Ok, so why a sparse matrix cannot be used here? What have you tried so far? Which programming language do you use? Please, check also the title and change it if needed (ie. "dense" vs "sparse" matrix).

Comment: It takes too much RAM and too much time to contruct the dense matrix. I am writing the algorithm in python.

Comment: You can use [Scipy sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) to reduce the memory footprint (probably also the time regarding the number of 0 in the matrix). Note that the kind of sparse matrix you need to use is heavily dependent on the computation applied.